# When Clicked edit button, corresponding details must be filled to the form for edit

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I have a form which can submited.and have list,that listed all submited form details.
[image]

I tried it in different ways.I want to fill the form with the corresponding details when I clicked the edit button.
Here is my php file

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <b>Leader Name : </b><?php echo($row["lead_name"]); ?><br>
    <b>Phone Number : </b><?php echo($row["phone_number"]); ?><br>
    <b>Email : </b><?php echo($row["email"]); ?><br>
    <b>Part Created Time : </b><?php echo($row["create_date_and_time"]); ?>
    <br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 ">

    <form role="form" action='index.php' method='POST'>
      <input type='hidden' name='party_id' value='<?php echo($row["party_id"]); ?> '>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block" id="edit" name="edit" value="Edit" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 3px;">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-block" id="delete" name="delete" value="Delete" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 3px;">
    </form>

    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        print("<script> alert('delete'); </script>");
        $party_id = isset($_POST['party_id']) ? $_POST['party_id'] : "";
        $queryDelete = "DELETE FROM party_details WHERE party_id='$party_id'";
        if ($conn->query($queryDelete)) {
          $_SESSION['party'] = "";
          $_SESSION['trips'] = [];
          print("<script>
            alert('Party removed');
            window.location.href='../tripCreate';
          </script>");
        } else { 
          print("<script>alert('Error when remove ! ');</script>");
        }
        $_POST = array();
      }

      if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
        $party_id1 = isset($_POST['party_id']) ? $_POST['party_id'] : "";
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM party_details WHERE party_id='$party_id1'";
        $result1 = $conn->query($query1);
        $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
      }
    ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: First of all, you need to remove the quote from ('$party_id1') here just use the variable. Then try again and check, hope you will get value and show them in form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you should specify not only result you want to achieve, but also what kind of problem you are facing.
is it php error, or information not being displayed in resulted page?

one thing i spotted is that you got `$row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();` but in form you echo `$row[]` (instead of `$row1[]`), which i dont see being created anywhere.

also, did you try `var_dump($row)` in php and check its content (or `$row1`...)?

Comment: I will try it.Thanks